# Value error. The view 'users.views.register' didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

Python 3.8.5, Django 3.1.6

I'm learning python and django with book Python Crash Course: A Hands-On, Project-Based Introduction to Programming (Erik Matthes)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWCKi.png)
Now I cannot continue because I cannot find a solution to the problem.

ValueError at /users/register/
The view users.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


def register(request):
    # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    print(request.method)
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if request.method != "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        print('\nelse\n')
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        print('\n'+str(form.is_valid())+'\n')
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username, 
                                              password=request.POST['password1'],
                                              confirm_password=request.POST['password2'])
            login(request, authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    re_path(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='learning_logs/index.html'), name='logout'),
    re_path(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register')
]
```

register.html

```
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button name="submit">Register</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'index' %}" />
  </form> 

{% endblock content %}
```

Pls help me. I've been trying unsuccessfully to fix this for a week now.
I tried various manipulations and nothing worked. This is my first question on StackOverflow. So, I apologize in advance. This is the last hope for the continuation of the work.

Comment: I'm the author of Python Crash Course. You can see the code from the book [here](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc/blob/master/chapter_19/users/views.py). But it looks like you're working from the first edition of the book, which is getting pretty outdated. The second edition has been out for almost two years now. You're likely to run into more issues with this project if you continue working from the first edition.

Comment: @japhyr , I am very pleased that my little problem has caught your attention. it is very nice. and I want to point out that your book is very well written for understanding. Recommend to all friends wishing to learn python. ANow I will use the second edition. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `views.py` should be in this way

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


def register(request):
    # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    print(request.method)
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if request.method != "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        print('\nelse\n')
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        print('\n'+str(form.is_valid())+'\n')
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username, 
                                              password=request.POST['password1'],
                                              confirm_password=request.POST['password2'])
            login(request, authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

The error is because you haven't returned anything in the view when the `request.METHOD` is not `POST`